# Bound mismatch: The type Foo is not a valid substitute

Tags: java, generics

I need to do something like:

```
class AbstractA<PARAM extends AbstractB<AbstractA<PARAM>>> {

    public AbstractA(PARAM arg) {
        arg.doStuff(this);
    }

}

class AbstractB<T extends AbstractA<?>> {

    public void doStuff(T onWhat) {
        System.out.println(onWhat);
    }

}

class A extends AbstractA<Foo> {

    public A(Foo arg) {
        super(arg);
    }

}

class Foo extends AbstractB<A> {

}
```

However, I'm getting this error at "class A extends AbstractA {":

```
Bound mismatch: The type Foo is not a valid substitute for the bounded
parameter <PARAM extends AbstractB<AbstractA<PARAM>>> of the
type AbstractA<PARAM>
```

How's that possible? 
When i try to work out the generics, it looks correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's draw it out. In

```
class A extends AbstractA<Foo> {
```

the type argument `Foo` is supposed to match

```
class AbstractA<PARAM extends AbstractB<AbstractA<PARAM>>> {
                  ^
                  |
                 Foo
```

where `Foo` is

```
class Foo extends AbstractB<A> {
```

Up to now, `Foo` extends `AbstractB`. Let's see for its type arguments.

```
class AbstractB<T extends AbstractA<?>> {
                ^
                |
                A
```

So what is `A`? Does it match those bounds

```
class A extends AbstractA<Foo> {
```

It seems to since `Foo` can fit the wildcard.

**However**, when `Foo` is used as a type argument, the wildcard needs to be taken into account, so it kind of looks like the following inheritance (and generics) hierarchy

```
Foo extends AbstractB<A extends AbstractA<?>>
```

which does not fit the bigger picture of

```
PARAM extends AbstractB<AbstractA<PARAM>>
```

So `Foo` cannot be used as a type argument there.

Comment: Well, that kinda sucks. Sometimes I wish Java had weak typing like python, working with stuff like this is just pain. I'm gonna scrap  and rewrite the whole thing now.

Comment: @MightyPork I don't know your use case, but I've honestly never had to go that deep in generics. Maybe there's another way around.

Comment: There's got to be.. I wanted to abstract out common functionality from two distinct systems, but apparently in this case DRY is not the way to go.